# SQL Server always running query every hour

Tags: session, target

I've been trying to figure out why sql server is always running this query every hour of the day.

```
 SELECT target_data FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet WITH(nolock) JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xes WITH(nolock) ON xes.address = xet.event_session_address WHERE xes.name = 'telemetry_xevents' AND xet.target_name = 'ring_buffer'
```

Please explain if you have the knowledge about above.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server expert, and maybe there is some scheduled task directly on your database.  From an external point of view, check to see who might be running this query.  Or, you could also check to see if any triggers would be running this query (in which case, you would need to hunt down the table associated with such a trigger).

Comment: No scheduled jobs running.  Sometime the query runs every other 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found myself here when googling the same query. This was the highest total CPU query on our prod servers. I found it was running every 5 minutes.
After digging into a few false trails (as we have a lot of monitoring stuff running), I finally just ran a trace and found the culprit.
[image: Trace of error]

A quick google easily found the answer from here - it is SQL Server Telemetry Service - which no longer became an option to disable on instance install from SQL 2016.

There are posts on how to remove it, but I found simlpy doing it via the GUI (SQL Server 201* Error and Usage Reporting) was the easiest way and updated the registery correctly.

Comment: How to disable SQL Server Telemetry or CEIP Services?
Let’s follow the  below steps to disable the Telemetry;

Log on to the host where you have installed the SQL Server
Go to Start > Programs > Select SQL Server 2016 Error and Usage Reporting
Unselect “Send Windows Error and SQL Error Reports…”
Unselect “Send Feature Usage Reports…”
Click on the options, make sure all components are unselected
Click OK

Answer (score 0):

Other posts suggest disabling using the "SQL Server 20XX Error and Usage Reporting" tool.  However, this tool would not open for me, a black screen would pop-up, then the program would crash.

I found the following solution:

Rename the file SqlWtsn.exe.config to SqlWtsn.exe.config.OLD

For my 2019 instance this file was located in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared

After renaming the file, the tool would open and I could uncheck the error reporting checkboxes.